# C# How to sort Numerical values in datagridview column in ascending or descending order(maximum-minimum or minimum-maximum)

Tags: c#

I Have three columns in a DataGridView like this

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tluz.png)

i want the sorting to be either in such a way, Column 'Name' sorted alphabetically from A-Z according to First name, i.e

```
 [Table][2]
```

OR column 'Name' and 'Position' sorted based on column 'Score' in descending order of value like this:

[Table][3]

i am using C#. thanks

Comment: where is your code buddy ?

Comment: Marked down because you are asking SO to write the code for you

Comment: @moxie did you solve your issue ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383929(v=vs.90).aspx why dont you search?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Sort()` method for the same, which takes column and direction.

```
ListSortDirection direction = SortOrder.Ascending;
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Name"], direction);
```